# break statement in for loop not working

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, break

I have a following code in which I am using break statement inside a for loop in the following way:

```
noBreak = True
def scanShift():
    i = 0
    for i in range(0,29):
        if s[i] < current < s[i+1]:   #1st if loop
            global noBreak
            if i in [1,3,5,7]:        #2nd if loop
                noBreak = False

            else: noBreak = True      #line1

            break
    return i
```

In case '1st if loop' condition is matched when i = 3 then after going to '2nd if loop' the program comes out of '1st if loop' without reaching the break statement. Thus my question is why it is happening in this way, shouldn't after executing '2nd if loop' it should go to the break statement and then break out of the for loop?

Comment: can you try placing your else body block on a new indented line? Also can you tell me where the variable current is coming from? I would like to try this on my system and give you the answer.

Comment: 's' is an array consisting of datetime arranged in increasing order while current is current datetime that is datetime.datetime.now().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized I don't have python currently installed on this computer.

Can you try running this to see what happens?

```
noBreak = True
i = 0
for i in range(0,29):
    if 6 < i < 8:   #1st if loop
        if i in [1,3,5,7]:        #2nd if loop
            print "here"
            noBreak = False
        else: 
            print "there"
            noBreak = True      #line1
        print "Going to break out of loop"
        break
print i
```

I hope the output is something along the lines of:

```
>>here
>>Going to break out of loop
>>7
```

Comment: I had tried out similar code and it was working but not working in the above code.

Comment: Have you tried formatting your code to be more similar to mine? Have you tried adding print statements like I did to try to identify the exact flow the program is going? Have you tried hard coding in a couple values to try to specifically test certain flows and check their output?

Comment: @user2673943 let me know if the problem persists, or if my help did in fact help you then please mark the answer as accepted or mark it as useful :) Thanks and best of luck!